# struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 12

Tags: python, haar-classifier

I am trying to follow a tutorial from Coding Robin to create a HAAR classifier: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html.

I am at the part where I need to merge all the .vec files. I am trying to execute the python script given and I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mergevec.py", line 170, in <module>
merge_vec_files(vec_directory, output_filename)
File "mergevec.py", line 133, in merge_vec_files
val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 12
```

Here is the code from the python script:

```
# Get the value for the first image size
prev_image_size = 0
try:
    with open(files[0], 'rb') as vecfile:
        content = ''.join(str(line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
        val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
        prev_image_size = val[1]
except IOError as e:
    print('An IO error occured while processing the file: {0}'.format(f))
    exception_response(e)


# Get the total number of images
total_num_images = 0
for f in files:
    try:
        with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:  
            content = ''.join(str(line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
            val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
            num_images = val[0]
            image_size = val[1]
            if image_size != prev_image_size:
                err_msg = """The image sizes in the .vec files differ. These values must be the same. \n The image size of file {0}: {1}\n 
                    The image size of previous files: {0}""".format(f, image_size, prev_image_size)
                sys.exit(err_msg)

            total_num_images += num_images
    except IOError as e:
        print('An IO error occured while processing the file: {0}'.format(f))
        exception_response(e)
```

I tried looking through solutions, but can't find a solution that fits this specific problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by going to the github page for the tutorial. Apparently, I had to delete any vec files that had a length of zero.

Comment: You can solve the problem without deleting those files.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this bit:

```
content[:12]
```

The string is not guaranteed to be 12 characters long; it could be fewer. Add a length check and handle it separately, or `try: except:` and give the user a saner error message like "Invalid input in file ...".